# Android + Proguard + Apache POI

Tags: android, apache-poi, proguard, android-proguard

Someone was able to get the Apache POI library to work after obfuscation. I read a lot of information, tried different methods, but still get the error:

```
a.a.b.a: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.create(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.newPackage(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I added the jars files into libs folder: poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar and poi-3.12-android-a.jar.

My proguard-rules.pro:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.openxmlformats.**
-dontwarn schemasMicrosoftComVml.**
-dontwarn org.w3.x2000.**
-dontwarn org.etsi.uri.**
-dontwarn com.microsoft.schemas.**
-dontwarn schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice.**
-dontwarn schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**

-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes
-keepattributes *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod,Signature, JavascriptInterface
-keep class com.google.common.**

#Parcel
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keep class org.parceler.Parceler$$Parcels

#Apache poi
-keep public class org.apache.poi.** {*;}
-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.** {*;}
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.** {*;}
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.** {*;}

#BUTTERKNIFE
-keep public class * implements butterknife.internal.ViewBinder { public <init>(); }

# Prevent obfuscation of types which use ButterKnife annotations since the simple name
# is used to reflectively look up the generated ViewBinder.
-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.apachepoicentic"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug{
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        // There are restricted packages used in some of POI code, e.g. java.awt or javax.imageio
        // I could not exclude these in the
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.17-beta1'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17-beta1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/poishadow-all.jar')
    //compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.17-beta1'
    //compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17-beta1'
    //compile files('libs/poi-3.12-android-a.jar')
    //compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar')
   /* compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar') {
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    }*/
}
```

Comment: check this out  might help ....https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/issues/5#issuecomment-283581644

Comment: Yes, I tried this proguard-rules.pro it didn't help

Comment: check this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968735/using-com-bea-xml-stream-package-on-android

Comment: Thank you, but there is no the decision.

Answer (score 5):

**EDITED**

From https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android

## Necessary System-Properties

In order to work around problems with finding a suitable XML Parser, currently
the following system properties need to be set manually during startup of your
application (let me know if you know of a better way to do this, see issue #10)

*From me : Just put those lines in your code before using the library*

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");
```

## Download the library

If you want to get started quickly, there is a ready-made jar-file available here https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/releases

You should be able to simply add this to your Android project and use the Apache POI
classes from it.

## For ProGuard

```
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.openxmlformats.schemas.**
-dontwarn org.etsi.**
-dontwarn org.w3.**
-dontwarn com.microsoft.schemas.**
-dontwarn com.graphbuilder.**
-dontnote org.apache.**
-dontnote org.openxmlformats.schemas.**
-dontnote org.etsi.**
-dontnote org.w3.**
-dontnote com.microsoft.schemas.**
-dontnote com.graphbuilder.**

-keeppackagenames org.apache.poi.ss.formula.function

-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl
-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl
-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl

-keep class schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sF1327CCA741569E70F9CA8C9AF9B44B2.TypeSystemHolder { public final static *** typeSystem; }

-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.BuiltinSchemaTypeSystem { public static *** get(...); public static *** getNoType(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.PathResourceLoader { public <init>(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemCompiler { public static *** compile(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl { public <init>(...); public static *** get(...); public static *** getNoType(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl { public static *** getContextTypeLoader(...); public static *** build(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale { public static *** streamToNode(...); public static *** nodeTo*(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path { public static *** compilePath(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Query { public static *** compileQuery(...); }

-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CommentsDocument { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTAuthors { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBooleanProperty { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBookView { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBookViews { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorder { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorders { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorderPr { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCell { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellAlignment { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellFormula { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellStyleXfs { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellXfs { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTColor { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCol { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCols { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTComment { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTComments { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCommentList { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDrawing { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFill { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFills { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFonts { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFontName { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFontScheme { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFontSize { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTIntProperty { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTLegacyDrawing { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTNumFmts { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPatternFill { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPageMargins { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPane { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRow { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSelection { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetData { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetDimension { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetFormatPr { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetView { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetViews { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheets { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSst { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTStylesheet { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRst { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbookPr { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTXf { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.SstDocument { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.StyleSheetDocument { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellType$Enum { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellFormulaType$Enum { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STXstring { *; }

-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CommentsDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTAuthorsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBooleanPropertyImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBookViewImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBookViewsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBorderImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBordersImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBorderPrImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellAlignmentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellFormulaImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellStyleXfsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellXfsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColorImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCommentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCommentsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCommentListImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTDrawingImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFillImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFillsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontNameImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontSchemeImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontSizeImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTIntPropertyImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTLegacyDrawingImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTNumFmtsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPatternFillImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPageMarginsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPaneImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRowImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSelectionImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetDataImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetDimensionImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetFormatPrImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetViewImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetViewsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSstImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTStylesheetImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRstImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorkbookImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorkbookPrImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTXfImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.SstDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.StyleSheetDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.STXstringImpl { *; }

-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.impl.CTPropertiesImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.impl.PropertiesDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.impl.CTPropertiesImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.impl.PropertiesDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl.CTDrawingImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl.CTMarkerImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.impl.CTIdMapImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.impl.CTShapeLayoutImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTShadowImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTFillImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTPathImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTShapeImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTShapetypeImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTStrokeImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTTextboxImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.impl.CTClientDataImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.impl.STTrueFalseBlankImpl { *; }
```

## Old answer (does not work on Android if ProGuard is enabled)

## If you use HSSF

( .xls => Excel '97(-2007) file format)
It was not easy but I succeeded. Simply set this dependency to Apache POI (ONLY, remove the libraries add previously ex : `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar` and `poi-3.12-android-a.jar`) :

```
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.16'
```

For the latest version see here : [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android)

## If you use SXSSF

(.xlsx => Excel 2007 OOXML file format)
Add this dependency to your `build.gradle`

```
compile files('libs/poi-3.12-android-a.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar')
```

## The ProGuard Rules for both

And for ProGuard just add the rules quote by @PN10 above:  https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/issues/5#issuecomment-283581644

```
# Optimize
-optimizations !field/*,!class/merging/*,*
-mergeinterfacesaggressively

# will keep line numbers and file name obfuscation
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Apache POI
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.openxmlformats.schemas.**
-dontwarn org.etsi.**
-dontwarn org.w3.**
-dontwarn com.microsoft.schemas.**
-dontwarn com.graphbuilder.**
-dontnote org.apache.**
-dontnote org.openxmlformats.schemas.**
-dontnote org.etsi.**
-dontnote org.w3.**
-dontnote com.microsoft.schemas.**
-dontnote com.graphbuilder.**

-keeppackagenames org.apache.poi.ss.formula.function

-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl
-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl
-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl

-keep class schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sF1327CCA741569E70F9CA8C9AF9B44B2.TypeSystemHolder { public final static *** typeSystem; }

-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.BuiltinSchemaTypeSystem { public static *** get(...); public static *** getNoType(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.PathResourceLoader { public <init>(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemCompiler { public static *** compile(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl { public <init>(...); public static *** get(...); public static *** getNoType(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl { public static *** getContextTypeLoader(...); public static *** build(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale { public static *** streamToNode(...); public static *** nodeTo*(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path { public static *** compilePath(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Query { public static *** compileQuery(...); }

-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CommentsDocument { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTAuthors { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBooleanProperty { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBookView { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBookViews { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorder { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorders { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorderPr { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCell { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellAlignment { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellFormula { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellStyleXfs { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellXfs { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTColor { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCol { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCols { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTComment { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTComments { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCommentList { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDrawing { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFill { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFills { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFonts { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFontName { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFontScheme { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFontSize { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTIntProperty { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTLegacyDrawing { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTNumFmts { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPatternFill { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPageMargins { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPane { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRow { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSelection { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetData { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetDimension { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetFormatPr { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetView { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetViews { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheets { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSst { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTStylesheet { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRst { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbookPr { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTXf { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.SstDocument { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.StyleSheetDocument { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellType$Enum { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellFormulaType$Enum { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STXstring { *; }

-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CommentsDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTAuthorsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBooleanPropertyImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBookViewImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBookViewsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBorderImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBordersImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBorderPrImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellAlignmentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellFormulaImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellStyleXfsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellXfsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColorImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCommentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCommentsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCommentListImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTDrawingImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFillImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFillsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontNameImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontSchemeImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontSizeImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTIntPropertyImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTLegacyDrawingImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTNumFmtsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPatternFillImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPageMarginsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPaneImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRowImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSelectionImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetDataImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetDimensionImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetFormatPrImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetViewImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetViewsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSstImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTStylesheetImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRstImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorkbookImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorkbookPrImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTXfImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.SstDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.StyleSheetDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.STXstringImpl { *; }

-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.impl.CTPropertiesImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.impl.PropertiesDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.impl.CTPropertiesImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.impl.PropertiesDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl.CTDrawingImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl.CTMarkerImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.impl.CTIdMapImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.impl.CTShapeLayoutImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTShadowImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTFillImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTPathImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTShapeImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTShapetypeImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTStrokeImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTTextboxImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.impl.CTClientDataImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.impl.STTrueFalseBlankImpl { *; }
```

Comment: Filol, thank you for detail answer. I removed the library? then added the line, but the program can't find the library - "org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet" I can't create a sheet.

Comment: I tried to use only one library and caught the error - Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.

Comment: @Delphian i have edited my answer, tell me if it answers your problem

Comment: Filol, I added two libraries into lib folder, then added two lines "compile file" and caught the same error. Are you sure that the gradle can interact with Jar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343870/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-exclude

Comment: @Delphian have you add all proguard rules ?

Comment: There are a lot of warnings and 1 error! In warnings I see - schemasMicrosoftComVml and  schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice

Comment: I added to proguard -dontwarn schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice.**
-dontwarn schemasMicrosoftComVml.**
-dontwarn schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.** and can launch the app. But when I tried to use POI features I caught the error what I wrote above - com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found

Comment: I do not understand, I did exactly the same things on my app, I even created an excel file and everything works

Comment: Filol, can you send me your test project? I will try to start on my computer? delphian@tut.by

Comment: @Delphian Sorry I have not had time these days. Did you find the solution to your problem?

Comment: I come back to you in a few days when I have more time

Comment: Filol, I changed my build.gradle a lot of time.That is why I can show you the latest variant. See in my first post

Comment: @Delphian I found another solution much easier but a little more limited for the creation of excel files (graphic ...). Try and tell me if it works. Do not forget to delete the old library, imports and proguard rules. Look at my answer published above.

Comment: thank you for your hard work. I updated poishadow library but i caught the error. I wrote about the error this https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/issues/14. I suppose the problem appears when I am trying to create SXSSFWorkbook sheet.

Comment: Use this : `Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();`

Comment: Filol it's impossible because only SXSSFWorkbook can work with a lot of data fast. I tried to use other Workbooks but they have a serious limitation.

Comment: In this case I am afraid that no solution exists to this day. But do you really need to store a lot of data in an excel file? Why not use a database instead?

Comment: I am using database but the users need excel file format for their own experience and analysis that is why it's necessary to load data to excel file. This solve relys on users demands.

Comment: Thanks you man for posting this! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the latest poi 3.17  without any significant modification to the original library for excel xlsx format and run this successfully  on android provided you have eliminate all those  duplicate classes bundle in the xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar and not forgetting these two required stax and stax-api jar library too . If you do  run proguard , please be extra careful not to obfuscate relevant important classes such as  com.bea.xml.** and the rest in the xmlbeans and some schema required by poi. ProGuard Rules Example as shown below. If the Api is less than 20 or below and in certain phone models , the full  drawing and spreadsheet package in the   ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar is somehow required to avoid class not found error.

[jar link](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.poi%7Cooxml-schemas%7C1.3%7Cjar)

```
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class com.bea.xml.stream.**{*;}
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.** { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.** { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.**{*;}``
-keep class com.apache.poi.** { *; }
-keep class schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.** {*;}
```

[link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005834/excel-export-in-android/48058151#48058151)