# Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I am working in Android Studio and when I added the line in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar'){
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    }
}
```

I caught the error:

> Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'

What is the reason of the error?

Comment: Don't think exclude can be used if you're just pulling in a file. Files don't have dependencies

Comment: @tim_yates, thank you. Maybe you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined the dependency, you applied the closure to `files` instead of `compile`.

```
files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar'){
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
}
```

Instead you have to make sure to apply the closure to `compile` directly.

```
compile(files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar')){
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
}
```

But I doubt it's necessary at all. Groups and modules are part of the Maven system and the JAR file itself doesn't have this information to exclude.

Comment: thank you. I tried this way but it doesn't work. Maybe you are right speaking that JAR file can't exclude the information. But I found some examples in Internet where developers using this scheme. I am not sure that it works.

Comment: What parts do you want to exclude from the JAR?

Comment: I can't obfuscate Apache Poi lib (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323942/android-proguard-apache-poi - my question about it) and I saw the recommend to exclude module stax api like I did above, but I caught the error about DSL method.